# PostgreSQL two groups segregated but not ordered only by zero price column

Tags: postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3

I need help with a bit of a crazy single-query goal please that I'm not sure if `GROUP BY` or sub-`SELECT` applies to?

The following query:

```
SELECT id_finish, description, inside_rate, outside_material, id_part, id_metal
FROM parts_finishing AS pf 
LEFT JOIN parts_finishing_descriptions AS fd ON (pf.id_description=fd.id);
```

Returns the results like the following:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| description | inside_rate | outside_material | id_part - id_finish - id_metal |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Nickle      | 0           | 33.44            | 4444-44-44, 5555-55-55         |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Bend        | 11.22       | 0                | 1111-11-11                     |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Pack        | 22.33       | 0                | 2222-22-22, 3333-33-33         |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Zinc        | 0           | 44.55            | 6000-66-66                     |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I need the results to return in the fashion below but there are catches:

1. I need to group by either the `inside_rate` column *or* the `outside_material` column *but* `ORDER BY` the `description` column but *not* `ORDER BY` or sort them by price (`inside_rate` and `outside_material` are the prices). So we know that they belong to a group if `inside_rate` is 0 or to the other group if `outside_material` is 0.
2. I need to `ORDER BY` the `description` column `desc` secondary after they are returned per group.
3. I need to return a list of parts (composed of three separate columns) for that inside/outside group / price for that finishing.

Stack format fix.

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| description | inside_rate | outside_material | id_part - id_finish - id_metal |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Bend        | 11.22       | 0                | 1111-11-11                     |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Pack        | 22.33       | 0                | 2222-22-22, 3333-33-33         |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Nickle      | 0           | 33.44            | 4444-44-44, 5555-55-55         |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
| Zinc        | 0           | 44.55            | 6000-66-66                     |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------+
```

The tables I'm working with and their data types:

```
                              Table "public.parts_finishing"
      Column      |  Type   |                          Modifiers
------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint  | not null default nextval('parts_finishing_id_seq'::regclass)
 id_part          | bigint  |
 id_finish        | bigint  |
 id_metal         | bigint  |
 id_description   | bigint  |
 date             | date    |
 inside_hours_k   | numeric |
 inside_rate      | numeric |
 outside_material | numeric |
 sort             | integer |
Indexes:
    "parts_finishing_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)


                           Table "public.parts_finishing_descriptions"
  Column    |  Type   |                                 Modifiers
------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
id not null | bigint  | default nextval('parts_finishing_descriptions_id_seq'::regclass)
date        | date    |
description | text    |
rate_hour   | numeric |
type        | text    |
Indexes:
    "parts_finishing_descriptions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The second table's first column is *just* `id`. (Why are we still dealing with a 1024 static width layout in 2015?)

I'd make an SQL fiddle though it refuses to load for me regardless of the browser.

Comment: Please clarify. `group by either the inside_rate column or the outside_material column ` is ambiguous. You mention a `price`, but it's neither in the query nor in the result, nor in the table definition. Add your version of Postgres and provide *proper* table definitions. Copy the output of `\d parts_finishing` in psql - that's a reliable standard format that trumps any manual description. And what's "Stack format fix." supposed to mean?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The price are the internet/external rates/materials that I *should* have clarified from the start, my bad. The "Stack format fix" is just a placeholder *between* the ordered list and the code block as Stack has a bug of some kind where it'll merge the two. I think I've got everything updated that you requested now.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I realized I can split the results in to two separate containers in PHP so this question isn't super-critical however if you still want to answer I'll add it to my documentation which I plan to eventually publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your question. Might look like this:

```
SELECT pd.description, pf.inside_rate, pf.outside_material
     , concat_ws(' - ', pf.id_part::text
                      , pf.id_finish::text
                      , pf.id_metal::text) AS id_part_finish_metal
FROM   parts_finishing pf 
LEFT   JOIN parts_finishing_descriptions fd ON pf.id_description = fd.id
ORDER  BY (pf.inside_rate = 0)         -- 1. sorts group "inside_rate" first
     , pd.description DESC NULLS LAST  -- 2. possible NULL values last
;
```

Comment: Thank you Erwin! I had to edit it a little to get it to work but without SQL fiddle working it wasn't going to be easy. I'm starting to question the point of the `GROUP BY` clause because it never seems to actually do anything useful in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do you have any reading suggestions then please? My current client does manufacturing and I'd love to be able to expand my ability to facilitate my client's needs. Thanks for your insight and for generally just being awesome.